# regex match question

Tags: regex

I want to match any of these cases with a regex. I have the header text, but I need to match it with the (possible) corresponding HTML:

```
<h1>header title</h1>
<h2>site | header title</h2>
<h3 class="header">header title</h3>
<h2>header title 23 jan 2009</h2>
<h1>header title</h1>
```

I have this:

```
/(<(h1|h2|h3))(.+?)".$title."(.+?)(<\/\\2>)/i
```

But it seems to not always work, and don't see why.

Thanks

Comment: You'd better give up on regexes to parse HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags (for example)

Comment: What language? .NET? Java? JavaScript? PERL? Different languages have different RegEx formats, so we need to know.

Comment: it's in php preg_match. I dont want to walk through the DOM since that would cause too much load (tried that).

Comment: I seem to be getting better results with a small tweak: 
/(<(h1|h2|h3))(.+)?".$title."(.+)?(<\/\\2>)/i

God knows why :p

Comment: Here's the direct link to the famed answer Manrico is referencing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regexes to parse HTML! Use an HTML parser, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is `$title` regex-escaped (so characters like `{`, `[` etc. are escaped)?

With line end may be problem too; there should something like multiline support, if you regex implementation supports it.

It is better to process structured data with appropriate tools - XML with XML parser, HTML with HTML parser. There are parsers like BeautifulSoup in Python, hpricot in Ruby, libxml2...

Answer (score 0):

What you (logically) want for your example is something like:

```
<(group of anything not including ">"> (Value to extract) <(group of anything not including ">">
```

e.g.

```
<[^>]>([^>]+)<[^>]>
```

The specific regex syntax is a bit dependent  on what environment you're working on.

You can get away with this if you're sure what you're parsing is no more complicated than your example. However, you *really shouldn't be parsing html (or xml) with a regex* (as someone has already noted here) because xml can be arbitrarily nested, and regex can't possibly deal with that.

Comment: it's in php, and actually I only want the header tags h1, h2, h3. So it would be: <h1, h2 or h3 * anything text string I know ending /h1, h2, h3>